# How do i make child elements with the same class appear only once

Tags: jquery, class, parent

My problem is that I have a parent element, in this case a div which is defined by  a class and no id.

Using a menu, I can make a call to a function that creates duplicates of the parent div which I can move around independently of each other.

I added this code to the function that creates the parent div.

```
function makeSmallBlockdiv() {
    $("#canvas").append('<div class="SmallBlock">SMALL BLOCK 350X300</div>')
    $(".SmallBlock").draggable({
        containment: "#canvas",
        scroll: false,
        grid: [10, 10]
    }, {
        cursor: "move",
        cursorAt: {
            top: 300,
            left: 175
        }
    })
    $(".Smallblock").append('<div class="article_title"></div>')
    $(".Smallblock").append('<div class="article_Image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="<? echo $image ?>"></div>')
    $(".Smallblock").append('<div class="font14"><? echo substr($article_text, 0, 200) ?></div>')
}​
```

I know the php code isn't going to work but that's not the problem; I replaced it with text and a valid image target without any luck

The problem is that the child divs propagate to all of the parents I have created.  So, I end up with two set of child nodes in the second parent and three sets of child nodes in the third and so on....

Is there any way to keep the child nodes with only a class definition and have them only populate the parent that created them?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the following:

```
var smallBlock = $('<div class="SmallBlock">SMALL BLOCK 350X300</div>').appendTo("#canvas");
smallBlock.draggable({
        containment: "#canvas",
        scroll: false,
        grid: [10, 10]
    }, {
        cursor: "move",
        cursorAt: {
            top: 300,
            left: 175
        }
    })
    smallBlock.append('<div class="article_title"></div>')
    smallBlock.append('<div class="article_Image"><img style="width: 100%;" src="<? echo $image ?>"></div>')
    smallBlock.append('<div class="font14"><? echo substr($article_text, 0, 200) ?></div>')
```

This will add the children only to the newly created `SmallBlock` div.

Comment: I just tried this and nothing appears, do I have to add more code to create the div?

Comment: how do i generate the newdiv, sorry but i am just learning jquery and javascript

Comment: The HTML inside the argument to `append` or `appendTo` is only what is required. It works fine for me: here's a [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsCxt/)

Comment: Wow, it works fine, I can add and remove individul elements with just a click.  Thanks so much.  I am sure I will be back for more help.  Chris